# UITableViewCell segues to different static UITableViewController based on row selected?

Tags: ios, storyboard, row, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I have 3 cells in a UITableView. Person, Car and House and I want each one to `segue` to a custom and different **STATIC** `TableViewController` so the user can do some setup.

What is the most efficient way to go about this?

In `prepareForSegue` do I query and call the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` then do what?
Or in the storyboards do I setup a push segue from one cell to a separate TVC, 3 times?

Does anyone know of any good tutorial? I dont know how to go about this thanks.

Comment: y you can try tag for each cell identify which cell is tapped?

Comment: Is there a more eloquent solution? tagging seems a bit like a hack to me

Comment: can you bit elaborate do you want to call another view Controller when tapping cell?

Comment: Are the 3 cells always in the same order? Because then you can just check the `indexPath.row` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and push to the correct `TableViewController`.

Comment: yes another UITableViewController

Comment: @JMarsh yes, so I design 3 custom UITVC in the storyboard? but how would i then segue to one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are using storyboards?  Are the cells static cells, and always in the same order?

If so I am guessing you have a UIViewController or UITableViewController in the storyboard which is populated with Person, Car, and House.

You then have 3 different view controllers that you wish to navigate to depending on which of Person, Car or House is selected?

As you are using prototype cells, I would do the following:

As previously mentioned, when creating the cell do:

```
[cell setTag:indexPath.row];
```

then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath do the following:

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

switch ([cell tag]) {
    case 0:
        PersonDetailViewController *personDetailViewController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PersonDetails"];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:personDetailViewController animated:YES];
        break;
    case 1:
        // Do similar for Car
        breal;
    case 2:
        // Do similar for House

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: I had difficultly doing this because they are prototype cells?

Comment: Yes to all your questions btw

Comment: **note to other readers i am using dynamic cells in the root controller but they are technically static because I load them with the same array of data everytime

Comment: Why tag? Just use `switch indexPath.row` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Actually the easiest way is to control drag from cell to view controller you want to segue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, do this:

```
if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
   // push to controller 1
}
else if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
   // push to controller 2
}
else if(indexPath.row == 3)
{
   // push to controller 3
}
```

Comment: instead of //push to controller 1. can you please edit your code to a practical use. So I have to design 3 custom static TVC's in storyboards but how do I hook them up and reference them in the code? hope that makes sense, ty

Comment: Why tag the cell if you are not even using the tag later on?

Answer (score 0):

First Connect your main tableview with three individual TVC and add segue for each add identifier for that

then in didSelectRowAtIndexpath check which indexpath has been pressed and call that viewController like below

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"view1" sender:self];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 2)
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"view2" sender:self];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 3)
{
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"view3" sender:self];
}
}
```

Then in prepareforSegue find which one view is called

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"view1"]){

        TableView1 *tableMenu = segue.destinationViewController;

       }

 else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"view2"]){

        TableView2 *tableMenu2 = segue.destinationViewController;

       }
 else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"view3"]){

        TableView3 *tableMenu3 = segue.destinationViewController;

       }
}
```

Hope this works if any mistake someone correct me thnx

Comment: So control-drag from table view 3 times and NOT cell?

Comment: yap control drag then add identifier